# Comparing service utilization across zip codes

Tags: r, inference, spatial, geography

I work for a nonprofit and we are trying to assess utilization of our services across our service area, particularly to identify any communities to target for additional outreach. We are working with 3 year’s worth of services data organized by zip code/zcta, although we may use census tracts in the future. As the size of the target population differs by zip code, we plan to calculate the utilization rate of services per 1,000 of the target population. Our data currently looks like the example pasted below but in practice we have around 20 zip codes:

[image]

My question is: how can I analyze the utilization rate to identify any zip codes that seem likely to have a utilization rate that is systematically lower than other zip codes and may therefore justify additional outreach efforts? Just by eyeballing the data above it looks like zip code 33333 is much lower than the first two zip codes, but it would be helpful to have a formal method to apply.